# Can't find a library project on the internet

Tags: android

A while ago I took over a fully developed project and it's my job now to keep it updated etc. Long story short, the project is using some library projects and one of those is now causing a small problem that I need to diagnose.

The library project is called "PortraitQR" and it's simply just a QR scanner.

I need to find the source of this library project so that I can read and learn more about it. I can't find anything about "PortraitQR" on google.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the package of that project should get you a long way here. Also check for readme files on the project.

PortraitQR seems to be an app on the Google Play Store: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=vn.mobilepro.labs.qrcode